# LWC RecordTypeInfos via getObjectInfo Unable to access

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am following a guide for how to get a specific record type for when creating a lightning-record-edit-form and I am getting this error thrown:

[image]

My Html looks as follows:

```
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name={caseObject}  onerror= {ShowToastEventFailure} onsuccess={ShowToastEventSuccess} record-type-id={recordTypeId}>
    some fields/grids here
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

JS looks as follows:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue, getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import CASE_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Case';
import Id from '@salesforce/user/Id';
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Name';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';



const fields = [NAME_FIELD];

export default class Culinaryrequest extends LightningElement {
    userId = Id;
    caseObject = CASE_OBJECT;
    @api objectApiName;
    @track objectInfo;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$userId', fields })
    user;

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: CASE_OBJECT })
    objectInfo;

    get name() {
        return getFieldValue(this.user.data, NAME_FIELD);
    }

    get recordTypeId() {
        const rtis = this.objectInfo.data.recordTypeInfos;
        return Object.keys(rtis).find(rti => rtis[rti].name === 'Culinary Team Request');
    }

    ShowToastEventSuccess () {
        const event = new ShowToastEvent ({
            title: 'Success!',
            message: 'Your Request to the Culinary team has been submitted',
            variant: 'success',
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

    ShowToastEventFailure () {
        const event = new ShowToastEvent ({
            title: 'Oh Noes! :(',
            message: 'Something is wrong with your Request please check that all required fields are filled out. If the problem persists please open a case with Real Estate Technology',
            variant: 'failure',
        })
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

}
```

If anyone has any ideas why this is being thrown please let me know as I am new to LWC and would love to learn!

Comment: Are you getting this error when adding the component in App Builder?

Comment: Yea, after its added to a App Record Page

Comment: I got the issue you were facing, added the details in answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After trying to replicate your issue (which I was able to), it turned out that your issue is on this import line:

```
import { getRecord, getFieldValue, getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
```

You have the **wrong** adapter here `lightning/uiRecordApi` for `getObjectInfo` resulting in all the issue where `objectInfo` never gets populated thus returning that error.

---

**To fix** this, `getObjectInfo` needs to be imported from [**`lightning/uiObjectInfoApi`**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/reference_wire_adapters_object_info) as below:

```
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
```

I used the example in [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.data_get_user_input) as a reference while trying to identify the resolution.

Comment: I did that and I am now getting a different error, afterRender threw an error in 'c:culinaryrequest' [Cannot read property 'recordTypeInfos' of undefined] (Yay) I tried seeing if specifying the object in     @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: 'Case' }) would fix it but it did not. Any ideas?

Comment: if you have a new error, you might wan to open a new post to avoid extended discussions in the comments.

Comment: @Jayant Das that didnt not fix it, I tried Glls approach of added an error handler and it looks like the first time it gets called both error and data are undefined, the second time it gets time it gets called it has a data property (with recordtypeInfos) but for some reason calls the else if (error)

Comment: @scarecrow You can actually use it that way. However it just works fine with what you have here. I though removed the not relevant things viz., User fields, etc. and it just works fine. You may be having some other issue here. Take a look at the documentation link that I have referred there, that should help.

Comment: @JayantDas Hmm, I will then create a new LWC and see if I just have something wrong in my current component.

Comment: @glls yeah that is super reasonable to do and If I cant figure it out I will def open up a new question. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: you'll get there =) happy coding! (if you hit a roadblock - new post - and well be there to help)

Comment: @JayantDas figured it out! not having <div if:true={objectInfo.data}>  
caused it to error out, I am guessing it was due to what frup42 was mentioning with race conditions?

Comment: @scarecrow Glad that it worked, because you didn't have your relevant HTML snippet here, so didn't realize that could be an issue. The documentation example and wherever you see it is a good idea to verify the `data` attribute before using it in the HTML. There's no race condition as such. It's just to ensure that the component has completed loading and that all necessary data is available before it can be utilized.

Answer (score 1):

Its very likely that there is an error that you are not catching.

If an error occurs in the adapter, for example when retrieving the data, error is populated with an error object AND data is set to undefined.

A quick suggestion would be to instead of wiring your response to a property, do it to a Function:

> Wiring a function is useful to perform logic whenever new data is provided or when an error occurs.The wire service provisions the function an object with error and data properties, just like a wired property.

this would at least allow you to throw an error that is meaningful, Ex:

```
 @track record 
 @track error;
 @wire(getObjectInfo, , { objectApiName: CASE_OBJECT })
    wiredCase(error, data) {
        if (data) {
            this.record = data;
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.record = undefined;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I just realised I missed some info in my question I have edited it to reflect the actual error, getRecord is working. What I am having issues is with getting the record type Id of the specific object

Comment: the error message implies that your `data` is undefined, so, it would seem natural that you can't fetch `recordTypeInfos`

Comment: @glls It turned out to be an incorrect import for `getObjectInfo` thus the `objectInfo` property was never populated, resulting in the error.

Comment: yes - i saw +1 =) , I merely suggested the OP to add error handling to their code, since, its not being captured.

Comment: @glls I literally ended up copying line by line and trying to troubleshoot by process of elimination with the example in the documentation until found that :)